# Perl FileSelect: Set window position

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I'm using Perl FileSelect from the Tk::FileSelect module.  By default, the FileSelect main window is displayed in the middle of the screen.

However, for my dual monitor setup, half of the main window is displayed on the left monitor and half is displayed in the right monitor.  I guess it is trying to display the main window in the middle of the combined dual monitor desktop.  But, I don't like how that looks.  I would like to display the FileSelect main window on only the left monitor.  I tried all kinds of -geometry => "+0+0" options, but I cannot get this to work.  Does anyone know how?

Here is a code snippet:

```
use Tk;
use Tk::FileSelect;
$a = MainWindow->new;
$b = $a->FileSelect();
$b->Show;
```

Comment: Is your question somehow related to perl programming? Is **FileSelect** only option? What about **Night Commander**? **-geometry => ....** applies to graphic mode and you should be able to move window by it's header to any place on the screen you desire. Your question is not appropriate to be here.

Comment: Yes.  This is a perl programming question.  I'm using the Tk::FileSelect widget (https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/FileSelect.pod) in a perl program.  For many Tk widgets, one can configure where the window is displayed.  I can't figure how how to do this for the FileSelect widget.  Manually moving the window with the mouse is not an option.I don't know what Night Commander is and a quick WWW search does not produce anything relevent.

Comment: I don't understand why you consider the question inappropriate.

Comment: It is not clear what is **FileSelect**, probably you need visit following [dialog](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php), [File selection box](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/The_file_selection_box)

Comment: if you consider your question appropriate then would you be so kind to provide the minimal perl code snippet to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: does your question states anything about perl **Tk::FileSelect** module?

Comment: I added the code snippet.

Comment: have you stated that you run the program in terminal window or graphics mode? Did you stated what window manager you run? GUI windows manager is responsible for placing windows in particular location on the screen. You need communicate to wm where you want to place the window and it's size.

Comment: Okay. That is my main question.  How does one communicate to the WM where to place the window and size?

Comment: now it is better, but please see [Tk::FileSelect](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Tk/pod/FileSelect.pod) documentation. Do you see any information which indicates that code allows to specify where to locate the window?

Comment: No.  I read the documentation.  There is no answer to this question.

Comment: There is a reason for that -- because your question about **Windows Manager**. [How to set window size and location of an application on screen via command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43106/how-to-set-window-size-and-location-of-an-application-on-screen-via-command-line).

Comment: At least you should say are you in Windows, Linux, MacOS X or any other system, what windows manager you use. For example Ubuntu - [17.04 How to set default window screen position](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930131/17-04-how-to-set-default-window-screen-position).

Comment: I'm using the default window manager in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Some programs have options which allow communicate information about position and size to windows manager. As I could see in the documentation for **Tk::FileSelect** it does not mention such possibility, then it mean that you have to communicate this information to windows manager yourself.

Comment: Now it is better - we know that you use Ubuntu but it is still not obvious what windows manager you use: Unitiy, Gnome, KDE, LXDE. For prolonged period of time Unity is default windows manager.

Comment: I'm using Gnome.

Comment: Please see following [webpage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/476963/unity-window-placement). And now ask yourself if your question is related to perl programming?

Comment: Please see if following [information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22207/quickly-place-a-window-to-another-screen-using-only-the-keyboard) helps.

Comment: Yes, this is a perl programming question.  I'm using the FileSelect widget from Tk::FileSelect module.  I would like to specify in the Perl program where to place the main window.  If you can think of a workaround to solve this outside of perl, let me know.  Until then, this is a perl programming question.  Even if you find a workaround, that would be a hack.  This would still be a perl programming question.

Comment: See the following [sample](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=459445) -- but I assume you already tried something of this kind.

Comment: Yes, I tried multiple attempts like that.  I also tried modifying the source code as well.  Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Well look at date when the code was posted, it was quite a while -- a lot of things changed since then. I think that it might be a good idea to look at [tcl/tk](https://www.tcl.tk/) as _perl Tk::FileSelect_ rely on **Tk**.

Comment: In Google search for 'perl tk geometry management' and dig into reading, even the information quite old you still will learn a lot from this book about **perl Tk**.

Comment: In Google search for 'mastering perl/tk' -- it is good start.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just figured this out.  In the FileSelect.pm file, which is something the user is not supposed to edit, I created a subroutine called Popup().  This subroutine has special meaning within the Tk framework.  I don't know what that meaning is, so the following might be a kludge.  But it seems to work:

```
sub Popup {
    my ($w) = @_;
    $w->geometry("+0+0");
    $w->deiconify();
    $w->raise;
}
```

Comment: You can do this without editing the file: `sub Tk::FileSelect::Popup {` in your own script. However it is certainly a kludge and there is surely a correct way to accomplish this, but I am not versed in Tk.